# ActiveX with Multiple Classid

Tags: c#, javascript, activex

I created this ActiveX Control and expose several classes to COM using `[ComVisible(true)]` so each class has its own classid(eg.GUID). I package everything inside a cab file with the following .inf:

```
[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
AdvancedINF=2.0

[Add.Code]
ActiveXInstaller.msi=ActiveXInstaller.msi

[ActiveXInstaller.msi]
file-win32-x86=thiscab
clsid={ 11EABF82-A840-48AE-B11A-A05DCAFCD0D4 }
clsid = { 60A1606C-7382-4EC6-A8F1-05428FAABE72 }

[Setup Hooks]
install=install

[install]
run=msiexec.exe /package """%EXTRACT_DIR%\ActiveXInstaller.msi""" /qn
```

Inside my Javascript, I created 2 objects:

```
var x = new ActiveXObject("ActiveX.Class1");
var y =  new ActiveXObject("ActiveX.Class2");
```

The first object(x) works fine and I was able to call methods to that class but for the second object I get "Automation server cannot create object."

I looked all over but cannot find any solution to this. Is there any way I can solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no experience with CAB files, but it seems strange to me that your section is pointing at an MSI file, and not a DLL, OCX or whatever. Which file would it register for this class ID? See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Perhaps the MSI is doing the actual component registration even?

Comment: From what I researched, The MSI installer registers the ActiveX Control on the device without having to manually use Regasm.exe from Windows to do it.  I did this all in visual Studios 2008. Please let me know if you figure out something